# Design generic process using template pattern

Tags: java, templates, design-patterns, abstract-class

I have a routine that I repeatedly doing for many projects and I want to generalized it. I used `iText` for PDF manipulation.

Let say that I have 2000 PDFs inside a folder, and I need to zip these together. Let say the limit is 1000 PDFs per zip. So the name of the zip would follow this rule: `job name` + `job sequence`. For example, the zip name of the first 1000 PDF would be `XNKXMN` + `AA` and the second zip name would be `XNKXMN` + `AB`. Before zipping these PDFs, I need to add some text to each PDF. Text look something like this `job name` + `job sequence` + `pdf sequence`. So the first PDF inside the **first** zip will have this text `XNKXMN` + `AA` + `000001`, and the one after that is `XNKXMN` + `AA` + `000002`. Here is my attempt

First I have abstract clas `GenericText` that represent my text.

```
public abstract class GenericText {

    private float x;

    private float y;

    private float rotation;

    /**
     * Since the text that the user want to insert onto the Pdf might vary
     * from page to page, or from logical document to logical document, we allow
     * the user to write their own implementation of the text. To give the user enough
     * flexibility, we give them the reference to the physical page index, the logical page index. 
     * @param physcialPage The actual page number that the user current looking at
     * @param logicalPage A Pdf might contain multiples sub-documents, <code>logicalPage</code>
     * tell the user which logical sub-document the system currently looking at
     */
     public abstract String generateText(int physicalPage, int logicalPage);

     GenericText(float x, float y, float rotation){
           this.x = x;
           ...
     }

}
```

`JobGenerator.java`: my generic API to do what I describe above

```
public String generatePrintJob(List<File> pdfList, String outputPath,
        String printName, String seq, List<GenericText> textList, int maxSize)
for (int currentPdfDocument = 0; currentPdfDocument < pdfList.size(); currentPdfDocument++) {
    File pdf = pdfList.get(currentPdfDocument);
    if (currentPdfDocument % maxSize != 0) {
        if(textList != null && !textList.isEmpty()){
             for(GenericText gt : textList){
                 String text = gt.generateText(currentPdfDocument, currentPdfDocument)
                 //Add the text content to the PDF using PdfReader and PdfWriter
             }  
        } 
        ...
    }else{
          //Close the current output stream and zip output stream
          seq = Utils.getNextSeq(seq);
          jobPath = outputPath + File.separator + printName + File.separator + seq + ".zip"
          //Open new zip output stream with the new <code>jobPath</code>
    }
}
}
```

So now in my main class I would just do this

```
final String printName = printNameLookup.get(baseOutputName);
String jobSeq = config.getPrintJobSeq();
final String seq = jobSeq;
GenericText keyline = new GenericText(90, 640, 0){
    @Override
    public String generateText(int physicalPage, int logicalPage) {
         //if logicalPage = 1, Utils.right(String.valueOf(logicalPage), 6, '0') -> 000001
         return printName + seq + " " + Utils.right(String.valueOf(logicalPage), 6, '0');
    }
};
textList.add(keyline);
JobGenerator pjg = new JobGenerator();
pjg.generatePrintJob(...,..., printName, jobSeq, textList, 1000);
```

The problem that I am having with this design is that, even though I process archive the PDF into two zip correctly, the text is not correctly reflect. The print and the sequence does not change accordingly, it stay `XNKXMN` + `AA` for 2000 PDF instead of `XNKXMN` + `AA` for the first 1000 and change to `XNKXMN` + `AB` for the later 1000. **There seems to be flawed in my design, please help**

**EDIT**:

After looking at `toto2` code, I see my problem. I create `GenericText` with the hope of adding text anywhere on the pdf page without affecting the basic logic of the process. However, the job sequence is by definition depending on the logic,as it need to increment if there are too many PDFs for one ZIP to handle (> `maxSize`). I need to rethink this.

Comment: I'm a bit confused; the code above adds a single `GenericText` to a list, is there more to it than this? The `generatePrintJob` method loops over the PDFs, then inside that loops over all the `GenericText`s; even if there were multiple `GenericText`s, if they all printed data to the same location, seems like that would generate a mess. If you want to associate a single `GenericText` with a single PDF, why not just do that?

Comment: You are not processing the files 0, 1000, etc.  They branch in the `else` and you only process the files in the `if`.

Comment: @DaveNewton: My plan for GenericText to be a flexible way of adding texts to the PDF. As you can see, it contain (x,y) coordinate as well as the rotation of the text. The abstract method `generateText(int physicalPage, int logicalPage)` is help generate the sequence number, like if I look at page 1, then the sequence number is `000001` or some other format, so that why I have that abstract method there, so the user can write their own implementation on how they want the sequence number to look like. I know the design have flaw. I am trying to get it right.

Answer (score 4):

When you create an anonymous `GenerateText`, the `final seq` which you use in the overridden `generateText` method is truly final and will always remain the value given at creation time.  The update you carry on `seq` inside the `else` in `generatePrintJob` does nothing.

On a more general note, your code looks very complex and you should probably take a step back and do some major refactoring.

**EDIT**:

I would instead try something different, with no template method pattern:

```
int numberOfZipFiles = 
      (int) Math.ceil((double) pdfList.size() / maxSize);  

for (int iZip = 0; iZip < numberOfZipFiles; iZip++) {
  String batchSubName = generateBatchSubName(iZip); // gives AA, AB,...

  for (int iFile = 0; iFile < maxSize; iFile++) {
     int fileNumber = iZip * maxSize + iFile;
     if (fileNumber >= pdfList.size()) // can happen for last batch
        return;
     String text = jobName + batchSubName + iFile;
     ... add "text" to pdfList.get(fileNumber)
  }
}
```

However, you might also want to maintain the template pattern.  In that case, I would keep the for-loops I wrote above, but I would change the generating method to `genericText.generateText(iZip, iFile)` where iZip = 0 gives AA and iZip = 1 gives AB, etc:

```
for (int iZip = 0; iZip < numberOfZipFiles; iZip++) {
  for (int iFile = 0; iFile < maxSize; iFile++) {
     int fileNumber = iZip * maxSize + iFile;
     if (fileNumber >= pdfList.size()) // can happen for last batch
        return;
     String text = genericText.generateText(iZip, iFile);
     ... add "text" to pdfList.get(fileNumber)
  }
}
```

It would be possible also to have `genericText.generateText(fileNumber)` which could itself decompose the fileNumber in AA000001, etc.  But that would be somewhat dangerous because maxSize would be used in two different places and it might be bug prone to have duplicate data like that.

Comment: Thank you, I understand what you said about the `seq`, the `seq` is actually a `final` version of `String jobSeq`. I forgot to have that in the code. Any pointer on how to have this better design? I know the design have flaw, I am learning to get this right. Thanks again

Comment: After looking at your code, I see my problem. I create `GenericText` with the hope of adding text anywhere on the pdf page without affecting the basic logic of the process. However, the `job sequence` is by definition depending on the logic,as it need to increment as there are too many PDFs for one ZIP to handle. I need to rethink this.